# How to install GTK# in Termux?

Tags: android, gui, c#, termux

I am C#-beginner and I want to develop C# applications on GTK#. I need to install GTK# on Android in Termux, but I can't, because package `gtk-sharp-3.0` does not exist in Termux's repository. I wanted to compile from sources, but I don't know how to. Please, tell me how to install GTK# on Termux. May be I should use proot-distro with Debian to install GTK#?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Android applications and setup are off topic here except insofar as the problem is in connecting to your computer.